# Changing HTTP to HTTPS using Apache on godaddy affected responsive menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, ssl, ssl-certificate

So, I recently bought a Godaddy SSL Certificate. I installed through apache and I uploaded the certificate, edited the .htacces file through godaddy.

The code in my .htaccess file was:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I used this blog to guide me:
https://in.godaddy.com/blog/instructions-for-how-to-redirect-http-to-https/

Following the blog, I used the redirect to a particular domain method which was:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ HTTPS://www.yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

However, I noticed that when I checked the mobile version, my hamburger menu was not functioning. As soon as I reverted the changes in the .htaccess, the menu was working again.

I'll insert the code for the navigation.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap');

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@800&display=swap');

body {
    background-color: black;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.page-wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
}

/* ======== NAVIGATION ======== */
 
  nav {
    background: black;
    padding: 5px 40px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    /*left: 0;*/
    width: 100%;
    /*justify-content: space-between;*/
    align-items: center;
    transition: 0.6s;
    z-index: 100000;
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  nav.sticky {
    background: /*#235d63*/
    black;
  }
  
  nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  
  nav ul li {
    padding: 15px 0;
  }
  
  nav ul li.items {
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    margin: 0 16px;
    text-align: center;
    order: 3;
  }
  
  nav ul li.items::after {
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    left: 0;
    bottom: 5px;
    height: 2px;
    width: 100%;
    color: cyan;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  
  nav ul li.items:hover::after {
    opacity: 1;
    bottom: 8px;
  }
  
  nav ul li.logo {
    flex: 1;
    color: cyan;
    font-size: 1.4375rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    transition: .4s;
  }
  
  nav ul li a {
    color: slategray;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 1rem;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  
  nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: cyan;
    color: slategray !important;
    font-weight: 700;
    transition: all ease 0.4s;
  }
  
  nav ul li i {
    font-size: 23px;
  }
  
  nav ul li.btn {
    display: none;
    color: cyan;
  }
  
  nav ul li.btn.show i::before {
    content: '\f00d';
  }

  @media all and (max-width: 1024px) {
    nav {
      padding: 5px 30px;
    }
    nav ul li.items {
      width: 100%;
      display: none;
    }
    nav ul li.items.show {
      display: block;
    }
    nav ul li.btn {
      display: block;
    }
    nav ul li.items:hover {
      border-radius: 5px;
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px cyan;
      box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px cyan;
    }
    nav ul li.items:hover::after {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>HOME | LD Music Group</title>
    <link rel='icon' href='images/favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon'/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@latest/dist/boxicons.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/c8e4d183c2.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="page-wrapper">

<!-- ===== NAVIGATION SECTION ===== -->

     <header>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li class="logo">Company Name</li>
            <li class="items"><a href="index.html" class="active">HOME</a></li>
            <li class="items"><a href="team.html">TEAM</a></li>
            <li class="items"><a href="merch.html">STORE</a></li>
            <li class="items"><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
            <li class="btn"><a href="#"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
  
 </div>
 <!-- Responsive Navigation Menu -->
<script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.btn').click(function() {
                $('.items').toggleClass("show");
                $('ul li').toggleClass("hide");
            })
            });        
</script>

<!-- JAVASCRIPT Code for Sticky Navigation Menu -->
<script>
    window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
        var header = document.querySelector("nav");
        header.classList.toggle("sticky", window.scrollY > 0)
    })
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

I also have a modal on the page, I don't know if that's relevant or contributes to it being affected. (Modal works fine on page).

Comment: try loading jquery form a https source

Comment: @gugateider This worked my guy, preciate it. Its funny how something so small can affect a lot haha

Comment: I'm glad it worked man, just keep in mind that everything you want to load it in will have to be https otherwise will fail

Comment: For sure man, I'm still new to this. So I definitely learnt something!